# How Can I set a C++ breakpoint programmatically in Eclipse, when a certian condition is true?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm working on Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04. I have a huge project with multiple files and classes. One member variable of a class is set to wrongly to zero somewhere during run time and I don't know when that happens.
I would like to be able to set a breakpoint **programmatically** to break once say x is set to zero during runtime.

How can I do that please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use breakpoint conditions for that.

Right click on the break point and set a condition in its property window. You can set a condition like

```
memberVal == null
```

See [this article](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F) for detailed instructions.

### Edit

Change all your occurances of your member valriable from

```
memberVar = value
```

to

```
SetMemberVar(value)
```

and set in that setter method a breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, I don't have a breakpoint, as I don't know where that member variable is assigned zero in code, it happens somewhere during runtime.

Comment: Then make your member variable only accessible due a setter method. And in that method set a breakpoint.